# Why am I seeing duplicate GTM Tags on PageSpeed?

Tags: google-tag-manager, pagespeed-insights

Quick question for those SEO enthusiasts around here.

I wonder why I'm seeing double tags on my pagespeed results?

[image: PageSpeed Insights Screenshot]

We have literally checked the whole site. We installed the script just once, and in the correct way just like GTM suggests.

Any ideas?

Comment: make a screen shot of your network tab filtered by `gtm`.

Comment: @BNazaruk I took a screenshot, here: https://paste.pics/8024874a26680d9bb4b88ef59cceb4a7